# How can my code create a code and call it then, in C?

Tags: c, file, machine-learning

I am beginner in programming and in C. I want to create a "machine-learning" rubik's cube solver. In first place, the solution of cube, will be accomplished, by random cube's rotaions. I want to save somehow these steps, of the first way to solution.
How could I create a part of code, outside the main code, that includes the commands of the first solution, so I can call it,in the second time, I ll run the program? Is that even possible?

Comment: Possible, yes. But as a **beginner** in C, why would you want to?

Comment: This isn't usually done by creating code. Instead, you save an encoding of the steps to be used. In the case of a Rubik's Cube solver, you encode each type of twist as a number, then create an array of those numbers.

Comment: It sounds like you would want to save the steps taken to solve the cube in a database.

Comment: I just want to try it, it is free.

Comment: You essentially need to write a compiler. This is an advanced programming project, not a beginner one.

Comment: "*the solution of cube, will be accomplished, by random cube's rotaions* [sic]" - the expectation for the number of moves for solving a Rubik's cube by random rotations must be astronomical.  Very likely more than you can reasonably hope to store.  And there is *no* upper bound.

Comment: "Random" rotation should only come in play when there is a metric associated with each move, and the top solutions do not agree.

Answer (score 2):

> In first place, the solution of cube, will be accomplished, by random
>   cube's rotaions

No, it will be NEVER accomplished.
Try throwing coin.

Comment: Its a 2x2x2 rubiks cube, so the combinations are less than 4 million.

Answer (score 0):

It will be highly unlikely you will solve a Rubik's Cube by randomly rotating, you can however generate a random state of the blocks in a Rubik's cube, and then calculate the rotations.

After that you could save the rotations required into a file, as well as the starting conditions of the Rubik's cube.